# Can i call an another function from my function in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: function, jenkins-pipeline, nested-function

I have two separate functions in my Jenkins pipeline and i want to call 1st function from 2nd function.

I tried following code.

```
def first(){
    return{
        stages{
            stage("test"){
                steps{
                    echo "ok"
                }
            }
        }
     }
}

 def second(){
     return{
        first().call()
    }
}


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
       stage("Run"){
            steps{
                script{
                    second().call()

                }

            }

        }

   }

}
```

is this possible or not. suggest me right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Your Jenkinsfile will look like this:

```
def first(){
    stage("test"){
        println "executing first"
    }  
}

def second(){
    println("calling first from second")
    first()
}


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
       stage("Run"){
            steps{
                second()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if solution helped, plaese consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#targetText=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)